# Which privilege level do drivers run in on Windows?

Tags: windows, x86, operating-system, cpu-architecture, windows-kernel

Until today I had understood that Windows only worked with ring 0 and 3 (it remain level ring 1 and 2 for compatibility). However, today I have heard that the drivers work at level 1 and 2, while the kernel at level 0.

Could you please explain to me, please?

Comment: Which "Windows"? I think Windows 95/98/ME used "ring 1" for (some) drivers; but modern Windows (based on the NT kernel) is very different and never used "ring 1", partly because it supports/supported other CPUs (MIPS, Alpha, Itanium, PowerPC, ARM) and some only have 2 privilege levels.

Comment: @Brendan well, Windows in general, but thanks for your summary it's very helpful for me. Could you suggest me any ebook about this topic? I would like to understand it deeply. Greetings!

Comment: @Brendan Actually, in Windows 9x, ring 0 is used for Virtual Device Drivers (VxDs), and then (AFAIK) ring 3 is used for 16 bit driver DLLs

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all OSes I can think of (besides OS/2) use ring 0 or ring 3 for drivers. The reason why is because rings 1 and 2 only hide some ring 0 instructions, meaning that the can't halt the CPU or anything. But they can write to kernel memory, meaning that they do really very little security wise. If you want secure drivers, then they have to be in ring 3.

Comment: It was possible to protect ring 0 memory from rings 1/2 using segmentation instead of paging, but I'm not sure if any OSes did so.